# Converting an anonymous user to a regular user and saving

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am writing a Parse Android application which uses anonymous users by enabling automatic user creation. I can successfully signup this user (to convert the anonymous user into a regular user) and after that, logging in. Both calls return successfully. When I then set data on the user object and trying to save the user, I get a stackoverflow in the ParseObject class.

My code looks like this (simplified example code):

```
user.setUsername("MyUserName");
    final String password = new PasswordGenerator().nextSessionId();
    user.setPassword(password);
    try {
        user.signUp();
        ParseUser.logInInBackground(verification.getPhoneNumber(), password, new     LogInCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(final ParseUser parseUser, final ParseException e) {
                if (parseUser == null) {
                    requestListener.onError(e);
                } else {
                    parseUser.put("phone_no", "123");
                    parseUser.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() { // This generates a stackoverflow
                        @Override
                        public void done(final ParseException e) {
                            int i = 0;
                            System.out.println("i = " + i);
                        }
                    });
//                                requestListener.onSuccess(null);
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The stack overflow is generated when calling saveInBackground on the ParseUser. The stackoverflow looks like this:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at com.parse.ParseObject.isDataAvailable(ParseObject.java:3212)
        at com.parse.ParseObject.checkGetAccess(ParseObject.java:3284)
        at com.parse.ParseObject.getString(ParseObject.java:2867)
        at com.parse.ParseUser.getUsername(ParseUser.java:401)
        at com.parse.ParseUser.signUpAsync(ParseUser.java:665)
        at com.parse.ParseUser.resolveLazinessAsync(ParseUser.java:1397)
        at com.parse.ParseUser.saveAsync(ParseUser.java:502)
        at com.parse.ParseUser.signUpAsync(ParseUser.java:681)
        at com.parse.ParseUser.resolveLazinessAsync(ParseUser.java:1397)
        at com.parse.ParseUser.saveAsync(ParseUser.java:502)
        at com.parse.ParseUser.signUpAsync(ParseUser.java:681)
```

The Parse version I use is 1.8.0.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution! Turns out you have to save the anonymous user first before converting the user into a registered one. If you save the user first, convert the user into a registered one and then do a saveInBackground, you won't get a stackoverflow. So the full code to convert an anonymous user is:

```
final String accountUsername = username.getText().toString();
final String accountPassword = password.getText().toString();
final ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
user.setUsername(accountUsername);
user.setPassword(accountPassword);
user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(final ParseException e) {
        if (e != null) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Signup Fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Signup success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            final ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
            user.put("phone_no", "31743379507");
            user.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(final ParseException e) {
                    if (e != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Save data Fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Save data success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Please note that the saveInBackground in the SignupCallback is optional. You could also set this data on the user before the signUpInBackground is called and save an extra roundtrip. This is pure for demonstration purposes.

Also, it is assumed the following code is placed in the Application class to allow anonymous users:

```
ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
ParseUser.getCurrentUser().saveInBackground();
```

Here you see the user is saved as soon it is created.

Answer (score 1):

```
findViewById(R.id.createUser).setOnClickListener(newView.OnClickListener() {        
   @Override

        public void onClick(final View v) {

            final String accountUsername = username.getText().toString();

            final String accountPassword = password.getText().toString();

            final ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

            user.setUsername(accountUsername);

            user.setPassword(accountPassword);

            user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {

                @Override

                public void done(final ParseException e) {

                    if (e != null) {

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Signup Fail", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   Log.e(TAG, "Signup fail", e);

   } else
{             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Signupsuccess",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        final ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

                        user.put("phone_no", "31612345678");

                        user.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {

                            @Override

                            public void done(final ParseException e) {

                                if (e != null) {

 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Save data Fail",             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Log.e(TAG, "Signup fail", e);

                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Save 
data success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    })
```